# Problemas en convertir proyecto a web en java

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf

Buen dia amigos, espero y me puedan ayudar, lo que pasa es que estoy intentando desplegar un proyecto web pero al querer ejecutar no me permite hacerlo desde un servidor de aplicaciones como lo es tomcat, jboss o was ni en Liberty, esto es lo que me aparece:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me aparece en ejecutarlo con los servidores antes mencionados, cosa que ya los tengo instalados y otra al querer hacer lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que entiendo es que aqui sería en convertirlo a un proyecto web pero al momento de marcar la casilla de Dinamic Web Module me aparece ese recuadro, podría por favor ayudarme a convertirlo a proyecto web, de antemano gracias y quedo al pendiente de alguna duda o comentarios. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

ContextRoot es el nombre del contexto, la ruta relativa a /webapps/ donde se va a desplegar en el contenedor Tomcat o su equivalente (suele ser el mismo nombre de la aplicación)

Content directory se acostumbra dejar con `WebContent`, que es el subdirectorio donde se crearán `WEB-INF` y `META-INF`.

PD. Recuerda que, adicionalmente, debes configurar el Tomcat o el contenedor/servidor web para que el proyecto lo tenga como *Target Runtime*. Ir a Server -- Runtime Environments

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y añadirlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualizado:

Ya se pudo ejecutar por medio del servidor web, por el momento tenía a la mano el servidor Liberty, pero al hacer las modificaciones me salió esta pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me salió un error en el ibm-web-ext.xml:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podría ser por el servidor de aplicaciones que estoy usando?